# How to add firebase cloud messaging to eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently the instruction given in firebase documentation is for android studio and not eclipse. Are there any instructions available on how to add the firebase to eclipse?

Comment: Switch to Android studio first

Answer (score 1):

As you already know the answer then why your are asking the question?.
Google has already told that they will not provide support for Eclipse.
Please see this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).You have to use Android Studio for the implementation of Fire base

Comment: indeed indeed .